# Chartjs v7.0 with plugin zoom, strange effect when use "drag" mode.

Tags: javascript, charts, zooming, chart.js

I try to use the plugin zoom from chartjs with the version 7 of the api. 
I would like to be able to zoom when the selection of a zone of drag is finished.
Once zoomed, I would like to be able to move the chart to reach the other values.

I have try the v4,v5,v6 whith the zoom plugin but the result is always the same : When I try to select the drag zone all the chart move, it moves incredibly fast and its begin difficult to use it.

May be I don't use correctly the plugin but I've tried some other configuration the result is still the same..

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
responsive: false,
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Test1',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
    },{
      label: 'Test2',
      data: [14, 16, 4, 3, 1, 2]
    }
    ]
  },
   options: {
   pan: {
  enabled: true,
  mode: 'x',
 },
    zoom: {
     drag: true,
     enabled: true,
     mode: 'xy'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/0.5.0/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="myChart" height=200/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in my project:

first changed :zoom: {
     sensitivity:0.5,
     drag: true,
     enabled: true,
     mode: 'xy'
    }

second changed plugin as in this post:
[pan on chart.js also zoom on line charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547854/pan-on-chart-js-also-zoom-on-line-charts)

my plugin version is 5.